# Fixing learning rate for gradient descent single variable

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials

I need guaranteed convergence to local minimum given initial value in $(0,6)$. The function is $f(x) = 30-61 x+41 x^2-11 x^3+x^4$. I have $x(i+1) = x_i - \eta (4x_i^3-33x_i^2+82x_i - 61) $.
What values of $\eta$ guarantee convergence of the above?